# after making a .exe file using auto-py-to-exe it didnt run

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I make a calculator. Now my desire to make a .exe file to use my python file.

so I use **auto-py-to-exe** and convert my script to an EXE file.

but when I run this file using mouse double click it didn't work.

My calculator code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.iconbitmap('miracle_logo_icon.ico')
e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)


# e.insert(0, "Enter Your Name")

def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))


def button_clear():
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_add():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math="addition"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_equal():
    second_number = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    if math == "addition":
        e.insert(0, f_num + int(second_number))
    if math == "subtraction":
        e.insert(0, f_num - int(second_number))
    if math == "multiplication":
        e.insert(0, f_num * int(second_number))
    if math == "division":
        e.insert(0, f_num / int(second_number))


def button_subtract():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "subtraction"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_multiply():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "multiplication"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_divide():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num
    global math
    math = "division"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0, END)


button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))
button_add = Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_equal = Button(root, text="=", padx=91, pady=20, command=button_equal)
button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=79, pady=20, command=button_clear)

button_subtract = Button(root, text="-", padx=41, pady=20, command=button_subtract)
button_multiply = Button(root, text="*", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_multiply)
button_divide = Button(root, text="/", padx=41, pady=20, command=button_divide)


button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)

button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
button_add.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)

button_subtract.grid(row=6, column=0)
button_multiply.grid(row=6, column=1)
button_divide.grid(row=6, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

**My code work when I run the script.**

[image: Calcluter running after running Script]

**Folder After Converting.**

[image: This is the screenshot of my folder and Gui is the .exe file]

**When I am using one file and run it. I am getting this virus error.**

[image: Using One File give me virus error]

I am a totally new user of auto-py-to-exe.

Comment: Add an exclusion this program in your antivirus. It always happened to me when I make exe. So adding an exclusion will solve the problem

Comment: ok. but the program also didnt run

Comment: Ok I will reproduce the error in my pc. Then I will suggest you fix

Comment: Can you please tell me what operating system you are running. Windows, Linux or mac

Comment: And which antivirus you are using

Comment: @RishabhSemwal I am using windows 10 64 bit.

and antyvirus is windows difender.

Comment: Ok I will see it

Answer (score 1):

Open Setting/Update & Security/Windows Security
Then Go to "Virus & threat protection" then click on "Protection history".You will see here the list of threats removed by Windows Defender. Search your file name and then "Allow" the threat from here. This will add your exe to the "Allowed Threats" section and then open your exe. It will work.

If it doesn't work, turn off the "Real-Time Protection" setting from the "Virus and Threat Protection setting".

If it still doesn't work then Open Command Prompt as an Administrator. Then type these two below codes and hit enter after each code.

```
sfc /SCANFILE=c:\windows\explorer.exe
```

```
sfc /SCANFILE=C:\Windows\SysWow64\explorer.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same result. Auto-py-to-exe is clearly a hack. It was written Trojans on windows defender. JUST DON'T USE IT

Comment: It isn't a hack... it is literally open source on GitHub. It would be banned from pip if it was a hack.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).